# Transpose sequential times data to derive duration

Tags: sql

I have a table of actions within a session and duration (milliseconds) between each step:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| | userid | sessionid | action sequence |   action    | milliseconds | |
| +--------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+ |
| |      1 |         1 |               1 | event start |            0 | |
| |      1 |         1 |               2 | other       |       188114 | |
| |      1 |         1 |               3 | event end   |       248641 | |
| |      1 |         1 |               4 | other       |       398215 | |
| |      1 |         1 |               5 | event start |       488284 | |
| |      1 |         1 |               6 | other       |       528445 | |
| |      1 |         1 |               7 | other       |       572711 | |
| |      1 |         1 |               8 | event end   |       598123 | |
| |      1 |         2 |               1 | event start |            0 | |
| |      1 |         2 |               2 | event end   |        54363 | |
| |      2 |         1 |               1 | other       |            0 | |
| |      2 |         1 |               2 | other       |         2345 | |
| |      2 |         1 |               1 | other       |        75647 | |
| |      3 |         1 |               2 | other       |            0 | |
| |      3 |         1 |               3 | event start |        34678 | |
| |      3 |         1 |               4 | other       |        46784 | |
| |      3 |         1 |               5 | other       |        78905 | |
| |      4 |         1 |               1 | event start |            0 | |
| |      4 |         1 |               2 | other       |         7454 | |
| |      4 |         1 |               3 | other       |        11245 | |
| |      4 |         1 |               4 | event end   |        24567 | |
| |      4 |         1 |               5 | other       |        29562 | |
| |      4 |         1 |               6 | other       |        43015 | |
| +--------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+ |
```

I would like to capture complete events -- sessions containing both an event start and end (some may have a start but no end, an end but no start, or neither -- I don't want those), and their start and end times. Ultimately I want to track duration by transposing the sequential rows of times into columns so I can calculate a difference. The above data table would ideally be transposed into:

```
+--------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------+
| userid | sessionid | full event id | start  |  end   |
+--------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------+
|      1 |         1 |             1 |      0 | 248641 |
|      1 |         1 |             2 | 488284 | 598123 |
|      1 |         2 |             1 |      0 |  54363 |
|      4 |         1 |             1 |      0 |  24567 |
+--------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------+
```

I attempted something like:

```
select a.userid, a.sessionid, a.milliseconds as start, b.milliseconds as end
from #table a
inner join #table b
on a.userid=b.userid
and a.sessionid=b.sessionid
and a.action='event start'
and b.action='event end'
```

However, that doesn't work since some users may have multiple event start and ends in on session (like userid 1). I am stuck on how to best transpose the times data for each event. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given your above data:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  `userid` int, 
  `sessionid` int, 
  `actionSequence` int, 
  `action` varchar(11), 
  `milliseconds` int
);

INSERT INTO test_table
    (`userid`, `sessionid`, `actionSequence`, `action`, `milliseconds`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'event start', 0),
    (1, 1, 2, 'other', 188114),
    (1, 1, 3, 'event end', 248641),
    (1, 1, 4, 'other', 398215),
    (1, 1, 5, 'event start', 488284),
    (1, 1, 6, 'other', 528445),
    (1, 1, 7, 'other', 572711),
    (1, 1, 8, 'event end', 598123),
    (1, 2, 1, 'event start', 0),
    (1, 2, 2, 'event end', 54363),
    (2, 1, 1, 'other', 0),
    (2, 1, 2, 'other', 2345),
    (2, 1, 1, 'other', 75647),
    (3, 1, 2, 'other', 0),
    (3, 1, 3, 'event start', 34678),
    (3, 1, 4, 'other', 46784),
    (3, 1, 5, 'other', 78905),
    (4, 1, 1, 'event start', 0),
    (4, 1, 2, 'other', 7454),
    (4, 1, 3, 'other', 11245),
    (4, 1, 4, 'event end', 24567),
    (4, 1, 5, 'other', 29562),
    (4, 1, 6, 'other', 43015);
```

The following query should get you where you want to be (you were on the right track):

```
SELECT 
  tt1.userid, 
  tt1.sessionid, 
  tt1.actionSequence,
  tt1.milliseconds AS startMS,
  MIN(tt2.milliseconds) AS endMS,
  MIN(tt2.milliseconds) - tt1.milliseconds AS totalMS
FROM test_table tt1
INNER JOIN test_table tt2
  ON tt2.userid = tt1.userid
  AND tt2.sessionid = tt1.sessionid
  AND tt2.actionSequence > tt1.actionSequence
  AND tt2.action = 'event end'
WHERE tt1.action = 'event start'
GROUP BY tt1.userid, tt1.sessionid, tt1.actionSequence, startMS
```

Giving you this result set:

```
userid  sessionid   actionSequence  startMS         endMS   totalMS
1       1           1               0               248641  248641
1       1           5               488284          598123  109839
1       2           1               0               54363   54363
4       1           1               0               24567   24567
```

The `GROUP BY` is important, because there are two rows with `action = 'event end'` and `sequence > 1` for `sessionid = 1` and `userid = 1`, so (I assume) we want the one closest to the current sequence, i.e. the `MIN(milliseconds)`. As you can see, it also allows you to go ahead and take the difference of the two columns in this result set, saving you the extra step you were planning :]

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4782b/15) of this query in action on MySQL 5.6.  You did not specify an RDBMS, but I believe the language used by this query should be simple enough to work in any sql engine.